# GWT Missing MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2 & MaterialIcons-Regular.woff

Tags: java, material-design

Get some errors from log

Missing :

http://127.0.0.1:9878/font/material-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2

http://127.0.0.1:9878/font/material-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff

Found : /font/material-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf

Network.log

[network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFNom.png)

from : https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/1092

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

is there a solution yet ?

Its open since

WOFF and WOFF2 files missing with 4.0.0 release #1092

Open

ChetanGandhi opened this issue on Oct 12, 2020 · 11 comments

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: using : https://github.com/google/material-design-icons
i get the described errors see link : https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/1092
wondering if there is a solution (can you maybe reformat it itss all in description ticket i guess)

Comment: if there were a solution the issue would be closed

Comment: i guess there is no responsible developer... to delete the includes :(
Sadly, Google allocates low maintenance and low support for issues reported by software developers having trouble using the Material Design icons library.

https://github.com/jossef/material-design-icons-iconfont/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

the files are simply not there

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font

look : MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf